# How to add menu items in specific position in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a menu item like this:

```
AddChild(new MenuItem
{
    Header = "Test"
});
```

However, the problem with that is that the menu item appears in the end (logically), now I'm looking for a way to add it to a specific position.

```
--A--
--B--
--C--
```

I want to add it between A and B. The XAML is like:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem ... />
    <MenuItem ... />
    <MenuItem ... />
</ContextMenu>
```

The code runs in context of the context menu. And I can access the existing menu items by their name `A`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
myContextMenu.Items.Insert( newIndex, new MenuItem() {Header="Test"});
```

Comment: Sorry, had a comment about the wrong AddChild method before in my answer, i changed that.