# is it possible to add combobox item between two items in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="Trainning.Mycombobox"
x:Name="Window"
Title="Mycombobox"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ComboBox x:Name="com_friends" Height="32" Margin="223,102,264,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Chandru"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Arul"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Anbu"/>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

In above code i added three items into combobox.
After then i added one item into same combobox dynamically.
Here the code what i wrote.

```
public partial class Mycombobox : Window
{
    public Mycombobox()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.

        com_friends.Items.Add("Bala");
    }
}
```

It's output will be like this

[image: combobox]
But i want to add the item "Bala" between "Anbu" and "Arul".Is this posible ?

Please help me...

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/10774735/620360.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    com_friends.Items.Insert(2,"Bala");
```

Where the first parameter is the index where you want to insert your new object.

Comment: Wow we literally posted in the same second.

Answer (score 1):

```
com_friends.Items.Insert(index, "Bala");
```

Should do exactly what you are looking for.